# In G++ 4.8, typeof still cannot be used with "::"

Tags: c++, gcc, c++11, g++, gcc-extensions

The following code does not compile under G++ 4.8

```
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    vector<int> v;
    typeof(v)::iterator it;
}
```

If I replace typeof to decltype, it works fine.  I know about a workaround with a template structure

```
template<class T> struct Self {
    typedef T Type;
};
```

and then

```
Self<typeof(v)>::Type::Iterator it;
```

but still its annoying.

Is this a bug which should be reported?  Or this is a feature?

Comment: Now that we have decltype, typeof is as good as dead. Why use it at all?

Comment: I don't like this word. Typeof sounds better and is shorter by 2 characters

Comment: *"I don't like this word. Typeof sounds better and is shorter by 2 characters"* Neither of these is a valid reason to use `typeof`.

Comment: You asked why, I answered you.  The question was not whether I should or should not use typeof, but if there is a bug or not.  Also, my code will not be portable to GCC 4.6 and earlier.

Answer (score 4):

Here I am just writing up [n.m.'s comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23142065/in-g-4-8-typeof-still-cannot-be-used-with#comment35386259_23142065) as an answer and expanding on it a little bit.

In C++11, we have `decltype` which can be used with `::`. Consider the following code:

```
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    vector<int> v;
    decltype(v)::iterator it;
}
```

The above code compiles cleanly with `g++ -std=c++11 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic typeof.cpp`.

Since `decltype` is standard and [already supported by gcc 4.3](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decltype#Availability) (released in 2008, 6 years ago), there is absolutely no reason to use the gcc extension `typeof` instead. Your code will be standard, hence portable, if you use `decltype`.

Comment: decltype is supported by gcc 4.3, but decltype(v)::iterator is supported only since gcc 4.7 or 4.8.

Comment: Oh, I did not know that. It is most certainly supported in gcc 4.7 because that is what I used :) And gcc 4.7 is already 2 years old.

Comment: I wrote in my question "If I replace typeof to decltype, it works fine.", so your answer just repeats what is already in my question.

Comment: @user31264 No, sorry, my answer gives you good reasons why you should not use `typeof` in the first place. If you *"don't like"* the word `decltype` or that two extra characters are too painful for you, then I am sorry, nobody can help you here.

Comment: The reasons are not that good. My code will not be portable to GCC 4.6 or less.

Comment: @user31264 Self-contradiction: You are complaining in your question that you cannot write `typeof(v)::iterator it;` with gcc **4.8**; then how does it matter that `decltype(v)::iterator it;` wouldn't work with gcc 4.6 if you are already using gcc 4.8? Then post a new question and complain about gcc 4.6. I bet that question will be closed really quick.